# How to use a function as a condition for if in JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, row, appendchild

Here is my code. In this if my row Key is Grand Total that should not be give me a link.

```
row.append("td")
  .append('span')
  .classed({ '2017': true })
  .attr('href', function(item) { 
    if (item.key != "Grand Total") 
      return (projectBaseUrl + item.key + "2017"); 
  })
  .append("a")
  .attr('target', "_top")
  .text(function(item) { 
    return item.key; 
  });
```

But if I give for append like this `.append(function(item) { if (item.key!="Grand Total") return ("a");})` It is not executing. It throws an error as *Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter*
So what I can do for this.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're attempting to do. *However* the `append('span')` is appending to the `row` element - not to the `td`. I suspect that the error is because the reference element is not what you expect it to be

Comment: Ok understood, but I have 10 rows and 10th row is sum of above 9 rows. I have append in all those 9 rows which is replicate in 10th row also. But I want to remove the append (which is enabling a link to that value). Is it possible?

Comment: OK understood, but I have 10 rows and 10th row is sum of above 9 rows. I have append in all those 9 rows which is replicate in 10th row also. But I want to remove the append (which is enabling a link to that value). Is it possible?

Comment: Show us a [MCVE] that we can run - your question is an XY Problem, where you've decided to not append something.  That's fine but your solution is too complicated to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row.each(function(item) 
        {
         var self = d3.select(this);
        if (item.key!="Grand Total") 
            {
                self.append("td").append('span')
            .classed({'2017': true})
            .append("a")
            .attr('href', function(item) {return (projectBaseUrl+item.key+"2017");})
                .attr('target', "_top")
            .text(item.2017);
            }
        else 
            {
                    self.append("td").append('span')
            .classed({'2017': true})
            .text(item.201717);
            }
        });
```

This helps me out from problem. Thanks for your input guys